# In double-slit experiment with single atoms/molecules, how does the "gun" actually work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, experimental-technology

In double-slit experiment with single atoms/molecules, how does the "gun" actually work?

How are the atoms/molecules "launched" to the slits?

Comment: That depends on the specific materials involved.

Comment: and it gets a lot more complicated https://phys.org/news/2021-11-molecules-atoms-double-slit.html

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-019-0663-9.epdf?sharing_token=O33eVSIkK0aQ5Ie5COVS2dRgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0MQ7n-_yUmyvBsKfkN6FLBu98G0Nrx30Fucun-h3w8WX9IlwWelmQLTVb70WHA4Y1pxsdPmhmq4QvZ3kk0dRycJILQYYHZN26qmO72UylFXKFgM9i70iUUDcZdPwblhMv0RzePEbjpRDvq9ofxAtGf2St2MnNM6St8f1-6gD-QwYzkZvijVVq7IL4Ooez8pU-m8K5t0y9M2Ww6qUYOP6EjDvaJWUyBsWCPgXP_iPn6uR2RPrOq7S9u0r_erbzusUs9v9EKWvUsBuhvt7hPk98UumyqeY997yGgHpHh5iash0NkqO62J5pvoGpm49QPlClA%3D&tracking_referrer=www.scientificamerican.com

Comment: @anna v thank you for the articles. It is a known fact that the experiment is performed with atoms and even molecules. And that it is a hard task to keep the appropriate conditions. But how does the gun work? How are the atoms/molecules actually launched to the target? In other words, how is the atomic/molecular "beam" actually created?

Comment: To form a molecular "beam", you just open a hole for gas molecules to leak out, and then open a second hole later so that only the ones moving in the right direction get through both holes, while the others bounce off.

Comment: @IvNik  it can be very complicated, look at the last link fig 1 "The molecular beam is created via nanosecond laser desorption , followed by collimation and TOF encoding via a pseudo-random chopper. "

Comment: a typical method is to charge the molecule with electricity .... then the particles can be accelerated by an electrode/voltage field.  All interactions with the screen are mediated by virtual photons (i.e EM forces) which cause the wave behaviour.  The EM field is very dynamic ... even before the excited particle has even started to travel there are many EM forces acting.